# How to keep reload / refresh the page or the link I want at Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I want to visit a page with www.example.com.
However, this page always redirects to msg.example.com due to some problems.

As the paged redirected, some JavaScript at Chrome console is not work at all.

Can anyone teach me how to do that?
Thank you very much.

```
var link ='http://www.example.com';
var i;
for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) { 
  window.location.href=link;
  i++;
}

var link ='http://www.example.com';

window.location.href=link;

setTimeout(function(){

var isDisable = document.getElementById('to-main-page-btn').disabled;

if(isDisable===true)
window.location.href=link;
},1000);
```

i tried above code. but all failed

Comment: What you want to do is not possible. If it were possible to redirect to another location and keep running javascript from the previous page load, there would be lots of unhappy banking customers with highjacked accounts.

Comment: I see. I thought chrome console could do that...
for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) { 
var link ='http://example.com';

if(window.location.href!=link){
window.location.href=link;}
}

i am trying to do this....
maybe just get a good chrome plugin to do so.